# How to delete a selected row in database android

Tags: android

I somewhat manage to get the data & stored in Database & also I displayed in Listview. Now I need to delete the selected listview i.e, corresponding row in a database. Can anyone help me pls.

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of your source code? It can be done in different ways, depending on how you implemented the `ListView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SimpleCursorAdapter or something similar, each row of your list has a stable id associated with it, which is your primary key _id field from your database.

Wherever you are deleting from, call listview.getSelectedItemId() to retrieve that id and use it to delete the row.

```
long deleteId = listview.getSelectedItemId();
mDb.delete("TABLE_NAME", "_id="+deleteId, null);
```